# Constraints for Postgres table column name from another tables row

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints

Consider this DDL in PostgreSQL:

```sql
create table table_data 
(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    table_name varchar(255) not null,
    column_name varchar(255) not null,
    column_type varchar(255),
    constraint unique_table_column unique (table_name, column_name)
);

create table table1 
(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    username varchar(255) not null
);
```

I want to create a constraint or check so that I can only insert in table `table_data` if the column exists in the table

For example:

```sql
insert into table_data (table_name, column_name, column_type) 
values ('table1', 'id', 'int');
insert into table_data (table_name, column_name, column_type) 
values ('table1', 'name', 'int');
```

This should be executed without any error

but

```sql
insert into table_data (table_name, column_name, column_type) 
values ('table1', 'age', 'int');
insert into table_data (table_name, column_name, column_type) 
values ('table2', 'username', 'int');
```

both the insert should cause an error as

- in first insert `age` column does not exists in `table1`
- in second case `table2` does not exists

Consider the creds used here have owner access to this database but not in other databases in the server (e.g. Postgres)

**EDIT**
Also want to delete that row from `table_data` when column is deleted.
And if possible automatic insert and update in `table_data` table would be great (but that doesn't seems to be so practical)

Comment: 1) Why would the first INSERT's not error out as `name` is of type `varchar` not `int`? 2) You will need to use a `TRIGGER` and associated `FUNCTION` to do this.

Comment: The required information can be found in `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that query wouldn't cause error because I wanted to check only of existence of the column in a table, but not the type of the column.
Though check for the type would also be great but don't need that for now

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that seems to be what I want. 
Got the data from `select * from database1.information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table1'`, let me try to implement with `check`

Comment: From [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): *CHECK ... Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row ...*. As I said you will need a trigger and trigger function to do this.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver oh ! ok got it. Thank You. I would try using trigger & function (I need to learn these stuff first).